# How to verify if any key is having null value from Json response in rest assured(Just have to verify if in response null value is there)?

Tags: rest-assured

{
"userId": "dummy1",
"userRole": "s",
"integrationId": "null",
"integrationType": "dummy",
"externalUserId": "dummy2"
}

Comment: do you have your trials or can you demonstrate you did some investigation of your issue on your own?

Comment: I tried with Json array but didn't worked I might missed something there, I have removed those currently I'm validating with one by one object for now-String body = res.getBody().asString();
   JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(body);
   Log.assertThat((jsonObject.isNull("Key")) && jsonObject.isNull("Key") && jsonObject.isNull("Key"),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Hamcrest matchers to verify that:

```java
package click.webelement.api.restassured;

import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;

public class ValueValidation {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        RestAssured
                .when()
                .get(new URL("https://60269516186b4a0017780505.mockapi.io/wec"))
                .then()
                .body("$", not(hasValue(nullValue())));
    }

}
```

**P.S.** - `https://60269516186b4a0017780505.mockapi.io/wec` is a mock that I have created for the test. Not sure for how log it is going to exist. It returns:

```json
{
  "userId": "dummy1",
  "userRole": "s",
  "integrationId": null,
  "integrationType": "dummy",
  "externalUserId": "dummy2"
}
```

**P.P.S.** - this `"integrationId": "null"` does not mean the field has `null` value. This is a string. Null value in JSON is set like this: `"integrationId": null`